# shoulder detection on a segmented image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detection, curve, bezier

As an input I have a segmented image of the upper body, I'm trying to detect shoulders from this image.
I minimized the region by a threshold calculated by simple known ratios between head size and shoulder width.

Now I have the shoulders region, performed edge detection on it.
Now I need to find the points of shoulders.
is there a fast way to detect the shoulder curves ?

I'm using Matlab.

This is my input image :

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "I need the curve point"? Can you attach some images to demonstrate what you have, and what you are trying to get?

Comment: Aha! It seems like you may have fallen into the trap of asking [an XY problem question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It very strongly looks like you're actually just trying to find the alignment line for both shoulders, but to get to that you're asking about how to do what you already thought of approach, instead of asking about how to achieve what you actually wanted to do in the first place. If that's true, it's totally worth rewording and retagging your question to reflect that real need.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for informing me about this ! edited the question I hope in a good way...

Answer (score 1):

Bezier Curve is just a mathematical description of a curve, (linear interpolation, using control points).
It is not a curvetracer.

If you need bezier curve descriptions, you would need to do a best fit between a bezier curve model, and the data. Before you get started, you should probably play around with bezier curves, to get a feeling of how they operate.

See here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33828-generalised-bezier-curve-matlab-code
for a Bezier Curve render, in matlab.
It displays the bezier curve, when you provide some control points.

There is a few methods to actually fit a bezier curve to a set of data, here is one for matlab (using the least squares method).
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15542-cubic-bezier-least-square-fitting

It will some times work nicely, and sometimes fail miserably, this is due to the least squares method, and the uniform parameterization used. It should work OK for your shoulder problem.

you need to extract the edge data, as data points, but that should be trivial

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! If there is a better faster way to do it please send me a link to read about it

Comment: The choice of curve, really depends on the application. The fitting algorithm depends on real time requirements, vs. accuracy. Without knowing the application context, or requirements, this advise would be guessing.  The real question is, what do you need the curve for?

Comment: An application for detecting bad sitting postures. starting from the shoulders, calculate the slope of the two shoulder points that creates a linear line and the angle, if it is wider than let's say 15 deg, it will alert the user. sending a frame every 5 seconds

Comment: So you need to determine a few things. How often do you need to capture an image, and how fast do you need to detect the bad posture.  (faster than frequency, but do you need it faster than that?). How will you model a good posture mathematically? - polynomials with low order is often the fastest representation, is that good enough?

Comment: typically you would need a reference (good posture) to determine if the current posture is bad ;)